# Error in using SELECT to set a variable value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have following stored procedure and I have identified the issue with the stored procedure is that using select to set the value of @DeliveryAddress variable and so for all the Letter Requests raised it is only retaining the last value which is in Requests. I tried using SET by explicitly setting each value used in @DeliveryAddresss Calculation but of no use as I ended of getting error that subquery returns multiple rows.

I am unable to understand what shall I change in this SP, so that for each value in @Requests, a different @deliveryAddress value is set and used for insertion in LetterRequest table. Please help.
Note #WorkFlowAcct is a temp table having around 10 unique AccountIds and for each account we have atleast one debtorid.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WorkFlow_Action_RequestLetterPref]  
AS
DECLARE @LetterID INTEGER;
DECLARE @LetterType CHAR(3);
DECLARE @LetterDescription VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @JobName VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @DateCreated DATETIME;
DECLARE @DeliveryMethod VARCHAR(7);
DECLARE @DeliveryAddress VARCHAR(1023);

SELECT @LetterID = [LetterID],
    @LetterType = CASE
        WHEN [type] IN ('SIF', 'PIF', 'PPS', 'PDC', 'ATT', 'CUS') THEN [type]
        ELSE 'DUN'
    END,
    @LetterDescription = ISNULL([Description], ''), 
FROM [dbo].[letter]
WHERE [code] = @LetterCode;


DECLARE @Requests TABLE (
    [AccountID] INTEGER NOT NULL,       
    [DebtorID] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [Seq] INTEGER NOT NULL,     
    [ErrorMessage] VARCHAR(500) NULL
);


IF @PrimaryDebtor = 1 OR @LetterType IN ('CUS', 'ATT') BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Requests ([AccountID], [DebtorID], [Seq])
    SELECT DISTINCT [master].[number] AS [AccountID],   
        [Debtors].[DebtorID] AS [DebtorID],
        [Debtors].[Seq] AS [Seq],       
    FROM #WorkFlowAcct AS [WorkFlowAcct]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[master] WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON [WorkFlowAcct].[AccountID] = [master].[number]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[customer] WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON [master].[customer] = [customer].[customer]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Debtors] WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON [master].[number] = [Debtors].[number]
    AND [Debtors].[Seq] = [master].[PSeq]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DebtorAttorneys]
    ON [Debtors].[DebtorID] = [DebtorAttorneys].[DebtorID];
END;


DECLARE @Street1 VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @Street2 VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @City VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @Zip VARCHAR(512);


IF @Pref = 'Letter'
BEGIN
    SET @DeliveryMethod = 'Letter';
    SELECT @DeliveryAddress = [Street1] + ' ' + [Street2] + ' ' + [City] + ' ' + [Zipcode] + ' ' + [Country], @Street1 = [Street1], @Street2 = [Street2], @City = [City], @Country = [Country], @Zip = [ZipCode] FROM [Debtors] inner join @Requests AS Requests on [Debtors].[DebtorID] = Requests.[DebtorID] AND [Street1] IS NOT NULL;
    IF @Street2 IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @DeliveryAddress = @Street1 + ' ' + @City + ' ' + @Zip + ' ' + @Country;
    END
END

SET @DateCreated = GETDATE();
SET @JobName = 'WorkFlow_' + CAST(NEWID() AS CHAR(36)) + CAST(NEWID() AS CHAR(36)) + CAST(NEWID() AS CHAR(36)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 126);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

--Updated params for current Letter Request Table
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LetterRequest] ([AccountID], [LetterID], [LetterCode],   [DeliveryMethod], [DeliveryAddress])
SELECT [Requests].[AccountID],
    [Requests].[CustomerCode],
    @LetterID AS [LetterID],
    @LetterCode AS [LetterCode],
    @DeliveryMethod AS [DeliveryMethod],
    @DeliveryAddress AS [DeliveryAddress]
FROM @Requests AS [Requests]
INNER JOIN @AllowedCustomers AS [AllowedCustomers]
ON [Requests].[CustomerCode] = [AllowedCustomers].[CustomerCode]
WHERE [Requests].[ErrorMessage] IS NULL;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

RETURN 0;
```

Comment: *"I ended of getting error that subquery returns multiple rows."* Then the error *is* telling you then problem (you should really put the full error in your question in a quote block by the way). Though I see no subqueries in your SQL. I smell a poorly written trigger on your table `dbo.LetterRequest` that *assumes* a DDL statement can only affect 1 row; which simply isn't true.

Comment: Side note: I very much doubt you need all those `NOLOCK` hints, and if you "do", then you have far bigger problems under the hood: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: In short, to allow for multiple records you should use a cursor. But you can probably do away with variables and cursors completely and just join to  `[dbo].[letter]` in the first place